# Get View's child programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

In my xml file I have 5 linearLayout containers, these contain a textview each one of them. Now programmatically I'm implementing drag&drop functionallity, this is how I asign it to each layout:

```
LinearLayout place1;
place1.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
```

But in this Listener, it's converting the layout to a view:

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    //...
```

When I drag&drop a textview to another layout container, I can get this textview's view object and also the view object of the layout where I'm droping it. But, I would need to get also the view object of the textview that contains the layout where I'm dropping the other textview.

For this, I've tryed to use getChildAt() on the layout's view, but seems that this method is not available for views, just for objects like LinearLayout.

So, how could I get that textview's view object? have to say that I need to do this, because I need to have booth textview's objects to exchange the text between them when I do the drag&drop, but if someone nows a better way of doing this I also would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Check the type against ViewGroup using instanceof and if available cast it.

Comment: TRY --- `for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); i++) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewGroup and access all the views in the layout.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);
```

then you can use `getChildAt(index)`